Approximating the right hand side of $x + y \ge y\exp \left( {\frac{t}{y}} \right)$ with secant (or chord)?
I am a network engineer who is working with some network optimization problem. Recently some of my convex constraint has the form of $x + y \ge y\exp \left( {\frac{t}{y}} \right)$, I know that exponential cone solver can handle this constraint. However, I really want to approximate the exponential perspective term $y\exp \left( {\frac{t}{y}} \right)$ with some secant (or chord) as shown in this post Approximating Nonlinear Functions: Tangents v. Secants. To prevent division by zero, I think this form is more appropriate $\left( {y + \varepsilon } \right)\exp \left( {\frac{t}{{y + \varepsilon }}} \right)$.
The reason is that I hope to be put it back in the form of LP,QP, SOCP (or even SDP), so that traditional method can still work on it instead of having to solve it by exponential cone solver. By working, I mean we hope that we can use ECOS or CVXGEN for our embeded application because of the speedy requirement. Our team is willing to accept suboptimal performance due to the approximation.
Could anyone with experience or insights in this area kindly clarify this matter for me ?

If I’m not mistaken, ECOS does support exponential cones

Is $t$ a variable or a parameter, and does it have a sign restriction?

$t$ is a non negative decision variable. It can still be zero but very unlikely to happen.

Could you provide bounds for $y,t$ variables? The are both nonnegative, but their upper (or tighter lower) bounds could help with bounding the nonlinear term

A sum-of-squares polynomial bounding argument can be invoked to eliminate any exponential cone requirement. First, define
$$
F(y) = (y + \varepsilon)\,\exp\bigl(\tfrac{t}{y + \varepsilon}\bigr).
$$
Introduce the variable
$$
u = \tfrac{t}{\,y + \varepsilon},
$$
so that
$$
F(y) = \tfrac{t}{\,u}\,\exp(u).
$$
An interval $ [u_{\min},u_{\max}] $ is chosen to cover the values of $u$ arising from all feasible $y>0$. A univariate polynomial $P(u)$ of some degree $n$ is constructed so that
$$
P(u) - \exp(u) \ge 0
$$
for all $u\in[u_{\min},u_{\max}]$. This can be achieved by expressing
$$
P(u) - \exp(u)
$$
as a sum of squares polynomial, for instance
$$
P(u) - \exp(u) = S_1(u)^2 + S_2(u)^2 + \cdots + S_k(u)^2,
$$
which forces $P(u)\ge e^u$ throughout that interval. Define
$$
G(y) = \tfrac{t}{\,u}\,P(u)
$$
where $u = \tfrac{t}{\,y + \varepsilon}$. Since $P(u)\ge e^u$ on $[u_{\min},u_{\max}]$, it follows that
$$
G(y) \ge \tfrac{t}{\,u}\,\exp(u) = F(y)
$$
for all $y$ that map into $[u_{\min},u_{\max}]$. The original constraint can then be replaced
$$
x + y \ge F(y)
$$
by
$$
x + y \ge G(y),
$$
noting that $G(y)$ is now a rational-polynomial expression in $y$. To keep everything in a standard semidefinite form, $P(u)$ and $P(u) - e^u$ are required to admit sum-of-squares representations on $[u_{\min},u_{\max}]$; that gives a single global inequality
$$
x + y \ge G(y)
$$
whose validity is certified by a sum-of-squares proof that $G(y)$ is always an over-approximation of
$$
(y + \varepsilon)\exp\bigl(\tfrac{t}{y + \varepsilon}\bigr).
$$

I dont really understand it, but what should I put into yalmip now ?

Did you take into account that $t$ is a variable and not a parameter (per a comment).
